# How do I write a NationBuilder partial template that displays uncached content?

Tags: templates, caching, liquid

I have written a partial template for NationBuilder using the Liquid templating language (as far as I know, Liquid is the only option).

```
<h2 class="latest"><a href="/blog">News</a></h2>
{% for post in page.blog.most_recent_blog_posts limit:3 offset:0 %}
  <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;"><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.headline }}</a></div>
  <div class="byline">
  {{ post.author.published_name_linked }} &middot; {{ post.published_at | date: '%B %d, %Y %l:%M %p' }}
  {% if post.show_stream? %}
    {% if post.public_activities_count > 0 %}
    &middot; <a href="{{ post.url }}#reactions">{{ post.public_activities_count }} reaction{% if post.public_activities_count > 1 %}s{% endif %}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  </div>

  {% if post.blog_post.content.size > 0 %}
    {{ post.blog_post.content }}
    {% else %}
        <p />
  {% endif %}
    {% if post.blog_post.content_flip.size > 0 %}
    <div class="continue_reading"><a href="{{ post.url }}">Read more</a> &rarr;</div>
    {%endif %}
  <hr/>
{% endfor %}
```

This partial is included on the home page using the subpage tag. Now, when a new blog post is added, it does not appear on the home page unless this partial is saved again and, I surmise, the cached render of the template is deleted.

Is there a way to rewrite the subpage tag or the partial template itself to force this template to be re-rendered each time a blog post is added? Or each time the page is loaded? Is there a setting somewhere in the NationBuilder dashboard that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. And I've worked on a couple of sites that update dynamically just fine using partials.

My only advice would be to ensure you have caching turned off in your browser while you test it for updates.

Alternatively you can use the `{% tag "tag_name" with "partial" %}` syntax to pull posts with a particular tag. That requires you to tag those posts however.
[Documentation for {% tag %}](http://nationbuilder.com/theme_documentation#display_content_from_pages_with_a_certain_tag_on_another_page)